# Trying to send a POST to an Apache server from a .NET server

Tags: .net, apache, post, get, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send a POST from a ASP.Net Application to an Apache server.
Here is my code:

```
Dim sResponse As String = ""
Dim webReq As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
Dim webResp As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim reqStream As Stream = Nothing

' GetPostUrl return the URL only without any parameter.
webReq = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(ub.GetPostUrl()), HttpWebRequest)

' GetQueryString return the data for the post (param1=value1&param2=value2...)
Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ub.GetQueryString())
webReq.Method = "POST"
webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
webReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length
reqStream = webReq.GetRequestStream()
reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
reqStream.Close()

Try
    webResp = DirectCast(webReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    If webResp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim loResponseStream = New StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
            sResponse = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd()
    End If

   webResp.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    WriteErrorInFile(ex)
End Try
```

When I send a POST that have a very long data value, the server return a 414 error URI is too long.
I know that normally POST don't have a limit for the data length.
I tried to send the same POST request to a sample .NET WebService and it works.

I asked the Apache server owner to send me the request that he receive and here is what he sent me:

> [28/Nov/2014:11:22:25 -0500] "POST /mywebsite/gateKeeper.php HTTP/1.1"
>   302 - "-" "-" [28/Nov/2014:11:22:28 -0500] "GET
>   /mywebsite/gateKeeper.php?xml_viewer=7faa62a61e008e3a315e8fd276f89a9b&cas=OPER%7CX%7C...

Why is the data sent in a GET instead of the first POST?
And why is the request is split into 2 requests (POST and then GET)?